# imagePullSecrets not working with Kind deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I'm tying to create a deployment with 3 replicas, whcih will pull image from a private registry. I have stored the credentials in a secret and using the  imagePullSecrets in the deployment file. Im getting below error in the deploy it.

error: error validating "private-reg-pod.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "containers" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec, ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "imagePullSecrets" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec, ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec, ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "template" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Any help on this?

Below is my deployment file :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-pod-deployment
  labels:
    app: test-pod
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-pod
    image: <private-registry>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

Thanks,
Sundar

Comment: Life used to be tough before Pulumi :)

Answer (score 30):

Image section should be placed in container specification. ImagePullSecret should be placed in spec section so proper yaml file looks like this (please note indent):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-pod-deployment
  labels:
    app: test-pod
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-pod
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: test-pod
         image: <private-registry>
      imagePullSecrets:
       - name: regcred
```

Comment: I tried the above. Deployment is getting created but the POD is not able to read the secrets . Image pull us failing. below is my yaml file.                                
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-pod-deployment
  labels:
    app: test-pod
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-pod
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: test-pod
         image: <private>
      imagePullSecrets:
       - name: regcred

Comment: Warning  Failed          5m (x3 over 6m)   kubelet, aks-agentpool-35896074-0  Failed to pull image " unauthorized: authentication required]

Comment: I'm sorry but I solved your problem regarding wrong configuration file causing error which you pasted in question. I would really appreciate if you could accept my answer. Also looking on Stack Overflow rules you should create new question describing your problems related to failure with authentication and kubernetes secrets.

Comment: @Sun Did you solve your issue? im having the exact same problem

Answer (score 15):

Very common issue with kubernetes Deployment.

The valid format for pulling image from private repository in your Kubernetes Deployment file is:

```
spec:
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: <your secret name>    
  containers:
```

Comment: Indeed this worked. Putting `imagePullSecrets` after `containers` didn't work for me.

Comment: this answer was very helpful. For anyone this answer still does not work: In my case I also had accidentally added a wired character in the secret name. Wasted 2h.

Comment: This answer worked for me.  For some reason the default docker credentials secret wasn't even getting used.  (When I deleted that secret no change).   This should be marked as the answer.

Comment: @TheOnin As far as I'm aware, order does not matter in defining the keys, but indentations matter, maybe in case you defined `imagePullSecrets` after `containers` you also had some more indentations?

Answer (score 1):

Both @Jakub-Bujny and @itmaven are correct. The indentation is really important in creating and using .yaml (or .yml) file. The yaml file has been parsed based on these indentations. So, both of these are correct:

1)
spec:
imagePullSecrets:
- name: regcred
containers:
- name: test-pod
image: 
2)

```
spec:        
    containers:
    - name: test-pod
      image: <private-registry>          
    imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regcred
```

**Note:** before you used the **imagePullSecrets** you have to create that using the following code:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry <private-registry> --docker-server= 
<cluster_CA_domain>:[some port] --docker-username=<user_name> --docker- 
password=<user_password> --docker-email=<user_email>
```

also check if the **imagePullSecrets** was created successfully using the following code:

```
kubectl get secret
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have created the secret,then please try to make it like the below .

```html
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-pod-deployment
  labels:
    app: test-pod
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-pod
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: test-pod
         image: nginx
      imagePullSecrets:
       - name: regcred
```