# Login to a GitLab repo from Kubernetes Python client

Tags: python, docker, authentication, kubernetes, repository

I have a Django app that uses the [official Kubernetes client for python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) and works fine but it only deploys (rightly) public registries.

Is there a way to execute a login and then let Kubernetes client pull a private image freely? I wouldn't like to execute direct `cmd` commands for the login and the image pull.. Thanks!

Comment: Apologies, I don't exactly follow your question; the supported way of pulling private images is to create [a `Secret` of type `dockerconfigjson`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#registry-secret-existing-credentials) and then reference that in [the `imagePullSecret:` of the PodSpec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-imagepullsecrets), both of which I would expect the kubernetes client for python can do easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's pretty easy to do using official Kubernetes Python Client.  You need to do two steps:

- create a secret of type `dockerconfigjson` (could be done by command line or using Python client) - you are putting here your credentials
- add this secret into your deployment / pod definition using `imagePullSecrets` so Kubernetes client can pull images from private repositories

**Create secret of type `dockerconfigjson`:**

Replace `<something>` with your data.

Command line:

```sh
kubectl create secret docker-registry private-registry \
 --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> \
 --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

Equivalent in Kubernetes Python Client (remember to pass in secure way variable `password`, for example check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209978/where-to-store-secret-keys-django)):

```py
import base64
import json
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

# Credentials
username = <your-name>
password = <your-pword>
mail = <your-email>
secret_name = "private-registry"
namespace = "default"

# Address of Docker repository - in case of Docker Hub just use https://index.docker.io/v1/
docker_server = <your-registry-server>

# Create auth token
auth_decoded = username + ":" + password
auth_decoded_bytes = auth_decoded.encode('ascii')
base64_auth_message_bytes = base64.b64encode(auth_decoded_bytes)
base64_auth_message = base64_auth_message_bytes.decode('ascii')

cred_payload = {
    "auths": {
        docker_server: {
            "username": username,
            "password": password,
            "email": mail,
            "auth": base64_auth_message
        }
    }
}

data = {
    ".dockerconfigjson": base64.b64encode(
        json.dumps(cred_payload).encode()
    ).decode()
}

secret = client.V1Secret(
    api_version="v1",
    data=data,
    kind="Secret",
    metadata=dict(name=secret_name, namespace=namespace),
    type="kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson",
)

v1.create_namespaced_secret(namespace, body=secret)
```

**Add this secret into your deployment / pod definition using `imagePullSecrets`: option**

Now, let's move to using newly created secret - depends how you want to deploy pod / deployment in Python code there are two ways:  apply `yaml` file or create pod / deployment manifest directly in the code. I will show both ways. As before, replace `<something>` with your data.

Example `yaml` file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-registry-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-registry-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: private-registry
```

In last line we are referring to secret `docker-registry` created in previous step.

Let's apply this `yaml` file using Kubernetes Python client:

```
from os import path
import yaml
from kubernetes import client, config

config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

config_yaml = "pod.yaml"

with open(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), config_yaml)) as f:
        dep = yaml.safe_load(f)
        resp = v1.create_namespaced_pod(body=dep, namespace="default")
        print("Deployment created. status='%s'" % str(resp.status))
```

All in Python code -  both pod definition and applying process:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
import time

config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

pod_name = "private-registry-pod"
secret_name = "private-registry"
namespace = "default"
container_name = "private-registry-container"
image = <your-private-image>

# Create a pod
print("Creating pod...")

pod_manifest= {
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "Pod",
  "metadata": {
    "name": pod_name
  },
  "spec": {
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": container_name,
        "image": image
      }
    ],
    "imagePullSecrets": [
      {
        "name": secret_name
      }
    ]
  }
}

resp = v1.create_namespaced_pod(body=pod_manifest, namespace=namespace)

# Wait for a pod
while True:
    resp = v1.read_namespaced_pod(name=pod_name, namespace=namespace)
    if resp.status.phase != 'Pending':
        break
    time.sleep(1)
    
print("Done.")
```

Sources:

- [Github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/501)
- [Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673919/kubernetes-python-api-client-execute-full-yaml-file)
- [Official Kubernetes Python client example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/pod_exec.py)
- [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#inspecting-the-secret-regcred)
- [Another Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)
- [Github topic](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/1748)

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor will test ASAP, but i think it made my day!

Comment: i'm applying this solution, but i noticed i'm using a V1Deployment andf not a V1Pod. as i see, V1Deployment doesn't have a imagePullSecret setting.. is there a way to add this property to a V1Deployment?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52192682/imagepullsecrets-not-working-with-kind-deployment).