# How to create a secret for service account using Kubernetes version 1.24

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl

I am using Kubernetes version 1.24, I have created a secret for my service account manually, but when I run `kubectl get serviceaccounts`, it is showing that I do not have any secrets for that service account?

Comment: You need to edit the `ServiceAccount` to add the secret in it. Simply creating the secret will not add it to any SA.

Comment: You can edit your service account by command:
`kubectl patch serviceaccount SA_NAME -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SECRET"}]}'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are on K8s version **1.24**

The **serviceaccount** won't create the **secret** automatically.

You have to create it manually.

```
kubectl create sa <serviceaccount-name>
```

**Example** :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: token-secret
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "<SA name>"
```

If you just want to [create the](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#manually-create-an-api-token-for-a-serviceaccount) [token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#manually-create-an-api-token-for-a-serviceaccount) you can use the : `kubectl create token <Name>`

Read more about it : https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/k8s-v1-24-is-unable-to-create-a-serviceaccount-secret-798f8454e6e7

Comment: I have added the secret using the ``kubectl edit sa <name of sa>``` command, but would I be able to configure it so that all future ServiceAccounts automatically creates a secret?

Comment: kubectl create sa will auto create the secret token for you however if with the edit you can edit the existing created secret and add to SA.

Comment: I have done that, but I am using Kubernetes version 1.24 and it is not creating the secrets for the service accounts?

Comment: When creating a service account via azure I am running into some issues since the service account does not have a secret associated to it

Comment: Oh yes if you are on 1.24 secret wont get created automatically for SA.

Comment: Great answer! And also, I concur: you can achieve this also through official Kubernetes Clients for Python, Java etc. I questioned this same thing years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759882/login-to-a-gitlab-repo-from-kubernetes-python-client). Hope it can be useful

Answer (score 3):

I had to search a little bit to get it all together: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/

Mainly it's just creating a secret resource file `secret.yaml`.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: <name of the secret>
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "<name of the serviceaccount>"
```

```bash
kubectl apply -f secret.yaml
```

And adding the secret to the service account.

```bash
# if you have already a serviceaccount you need only the edit line
kubectl create serviceaccount <name of the serviceaccount>
kubectl edit serviceaccount <name of the serviceaccount>
```

And then just add the created secret (last two lines):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-04-19T06:31:47Z"
  name: <name of the serviceaccount>
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "312345558"
  uid: 92f6ac28-cab4-41d2-b861-6e998a7cb644
secrets:
- name: <name of the manual created secret>
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a `secret` manually, it needs to be *manually* added to the `ServiceAccount`. You can use `kubectl edit` for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

SA_NAME="${1}"

kubectl create sa "$SA_NAME"

# Generate a random string for the token name
TOKEN_NAME=$(openssl rand -hex 5)

kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: "${SA_NAME}-token-${TOKEN_NAME}"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "$SA_NAME"
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
EOF
```

```
./create_sa.sh jenkins
```

It will create a service account with name "jenkins" and generate a token for this service account